# How do i loop through a sliced ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, slice

`

```
     pix = cv2.imread(dirname2)
     pix=pix.reshape((1,144,256,3))

     pix[0:10,:,:,:]=pix[0:10,:,:,:]*0

     print(pix)

     framestack=[]

     for x in range(0,10):

         pix[x,:,:,:,:]=255
         pix[0:10,:,:,:]=pix[0:10,:,:,:]*0
                                   `
```

Hallo
i would like to slice an image in such a way that when i multiply that slice by 0, i make all the first 1000 pixel channels equal to zero.

Right now it makes all the first 10 rows of the image equal to zero.

then within the loop i would like to turn on each pixel channels value to 255 in turn, one after the other , but turning the values back to zero for previous itterations or slots when progressing.  from those 1000 pixel channels we made equal to zero.
My problem is heavily flawed slicing technique.

Comment: How does the `1000` fit with shapes (144,256)?  A shape like that suggests 1 image with shape 144 x 256, with 3 channels (RGB).  Maybe you want to reshape the array to (144*256, 3), so it's viewed as a 'flat' array of 3 element pixels.  Then just sequentially act on `arr(i: i+1000, :)` etc.

Comment: there are a thousand images stacked together

Comment: If you don't clearly explain the problem, you won't get a good answer, and likely no answer at all. If we have to guess things we'll skip your question.

Comment: there are a thousand images stacked together and i want to have a way of identifying each of the 1000, by having each of the first thousand pixels of each image being a zero except for one slot. So each image has a 1 in a different slot

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over nth dimension:

```
for x in np.rollaxis(data, n+1):
    print(x)
```

Comment: How does it know to stop after 1000 pixels? Im not clear on the n+1 part.

Comment: ok , I check to see if a count = 1000 then break out of the loop if it is......also i can do this for both parts by first iterating over it and multiplying the element by zero...but will it do what i want or will it alter whole subarrays, or delete pixels in a sporadic manner?

Comment: I am getting an error , axis out of bounds when i use 5 instead of n+1...please help